# Should we answer question with no attached user?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

The question [Can I get some tips or criticisms of this couch plan?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/can-i-get-some-tips-or-criticisms-of-this-couch-plan) looks like the user account has been deleted. Is it a waste of effort to answer this? Especially since it would only serve the OP, and his specific plan, so I don't see this having community value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a migration from DIY.SE from a [user](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/36062/djvs) that doesn't have an account linked to one on wooworking.SE yet.

The original user will be notified that the question is migrated and will get a chance to link his account to the one asking the question.

Comment: Thats why.... never seen one before. Thanks Ratchet

Answer (score 2):

Since ratchet freak addressed the case for this question specifically. Generally, a question that only serves the OP is not on topic on SE sites, so it should be put on hold and then closed.

If a user were to ask a *good* question and then delete their account, it's definitely good practice to answer it as best as we can. The mindset you should have is that we're answering questions to primarily help all future visitors to the site, not just the OP.

Comment: My understanding was that, at some point, "closed" was replaced with the euphemism, "on hold," across all SE sites. Is there a separate "closed" status?

Comment: I was up late last night and saw it had been recommended for migration to WW.SE, and told them it was ok to migrate it. In hindsight, I agree with you that this question is off-topic as it's currently written but I wonder if we can salvage it by reframing it as a couch design question: "How do I go about designing a couch? Here's what I have so far, and here's how I arrived at this. What other issues have I not considered?" I think such an edit would make it at least as on-topic as the several questions which asked, "Is this strong enough?" but weren't closed.

Comment: @rob, oh, you might be right about "closed" status being replaced with "on hold". I know I've seen both but haven't paid close enough attention.

Comment: @rob, I think reframing it like that improves it quite a bit and makes it on topic. It'd be a good question, showing a lot of research.

Comment: I looked into it some more and found that a question is closed automatically if it hasn't been reopened within 5 days. http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions